# Where could $(SrcDir) possibly be defined?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I've recently taken over the build responsibilities at a new company and I'm trying to decipher how their builds work (TFS 2013) and in quite a few files I see that code is copied to $(SrcDir)\ *someDestination*, but I can't find where SrcDir is defined.

I've searched every file in source control (using file explorer with Search File Contents on) and can't find it defined anywhere and I've even checked the environment variables on the build server, but I can't find anything that defines SrcDir. If it was SourceDir I know that's defined in the Build Agent Properties under Working Directory, but not SrcDir.

Comment: It must be being imported somewhere. Have you checked the TeamBuildTypes folder?

Comment: "...in quite a few files I see that code..." In which files? The project files? What exactly are you searching for when you search every file in source control? `$(SrcDir)` would be the usage, not the definition. The definition would be an XML element (e.g. `<SrcDir ...>`).

Comment: Kenneth - I'm searching all files for just the text SrcDir. Mostly I see it in .proj files. We're using InstallShield and I've looked at the InstallShield build definition and I don't see it there either.

Comment: Juan - where is that folder? It can't be part of my source tree because I've mapped $\ to a local folder and searched that entire folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It's in the MSBuild Arguments of the build definition:

[image]